# Providing input to prompts that automatically display upon login to a device in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I have a device I'm trying to connect to via SSH, in order to automate its configuration. Normally when you first connect to the device, it asks you to set up [a local administration account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs0qT.png) We don't want to configure this account automatically, because it defeats the purpose of automating this configuration.

Using [ssh.net](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET), I've tried to connect to the device, but authentication is refused.

```
using (SshClient client = new SshClient("10.10.10.41", 22, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    SshCommand command = client.CreateCommand(newUsername)
    command.execute

    command = client.CreateCommand(newPassword)
    command.execute
}
```

Is there a way to use SSH commands to set up the admin account? It should be as simply as sending a username and password, but if you it won't authenticate, I can't send any commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the prompt to type username and password by using `ShellStream` and `Expect` method.

```
using (SshClient client = new SshClient("10.10.10.41", 22, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    ShellStream shellStream = client.CreateShellStream(string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    shellStream.Expect("Please create a local administrator account."); // probably can be omitted
    shellStream.Expect("Username:"); // Expect has more parameters 
    shellStream.WriteLine(newUsername);
    shellStream.Expect("Password:"); // prompt to type password
    shellStream.WriteLine(newPassword);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Just for the others who visit this page: This is for "devices" only, which usually have limited SSH implementation, which does not allow better approaches. For full-featured SSH servers, using "shell" channel/stream is not the right way. +1